# animação sai do lugar quando eu diminuo o zoom

Tags: css3, css-animations

bom dia, sou um programador iniciante, estava fazendo uma animação em css do sistema solar com divs, o problema é que nem todos os elementos cabem no mesmo espaço quando o zoom está normal então quando eu diminuo o zoom, eles sai do lugar (menos o sol que nao é animado). Tentei usar o display flex, mas quando faço isso a animação para

vou postar o código css do mercúrio e do sol, porque os outros são bem parecidos com ele

```
#mercurio {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:white;
position:absolute;
left: 660px;
top: 300px;

animation-name: mercurio;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

}

```
 #sol{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top:250px;
  text-decoration-color: white;
```

agora o html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Sistema Solar

```
<div id="sol"></div>
<div id="mercurio"></div>
<div id="venus"></div>
<div id="terra"></div>
<div id="marte"></div>
<div id="jupiter"></div>
<div id="saturno"></div>
<div id="urano"></div>
<div id="netuno"></div>
```

Comment: Cara coloca o html, de forma que pelo menos de para simular o seu problema ;)

Comment: perdao hugo, sou novo no site assim como programador não sei muito bem como usar, agora está dando para executar o código?

Answer (score -3):

No HTML:

```
      <div id="sol">
        <div id="mercurio"></div>
        <div id="venus"></div>
        <div id="terra"></div>
        <div id="marte"></div>
        <div id="jupiter"></div>
        <div id="saturno"></div>
        <div id="urano"></div>
        <div id="netuno"></div>
      </div>
```

No CSS:

```
#mercurio {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    background-color:rgb(190, 39, 39);

    animation-name: mercurio;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}
    
#sol{
    position: relative;
    top:250px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-decoration-color: white;
}
@keyframes mercurio{
    from{
        left:0px;
    }
    to{
        left: 100px;
    }
}
```

Vou explicar como funciona o `position: absolute`.
O `position: absolute`, faz com que a tag com esse atributo fique "presa" dentro da primeira tag `positon: relative` que ela esteja dentro.
Então do seu jeito ele fez o seguinte: a tag mercurio é filha mais proxima de qual tag com position Relative? o body? então ele verifica e vê que não, o body é `position: static`,então ele ve a tag HTML, e vê se é position relative então ele vê que tambem não, então já que não tem nenhuma tag acima, ele fica "preso" dentro do começo do site, se você desse `top:0px` ele iria para o topo do site.

Então quando diminuir ou aumentar o zoom, modificar o tamanho de tudo, tambem dos pixels, então do jeito que ele tava, o sol aumentava o tamanho/diminuia, e os pixels dele tambem, e a diferença entre o topo da pagina e o sol tambem mudava, fazendo que a tag do mercurio se movesse.

Na minha edição eu botei a div do mercurio (e dos outros planetas) dentro da div "Sol", assim ao colocar `top:0px` ele vai no começo da div sol.
então quando dar zoom, ele vai continuar X pixel da div SOL e não X pixels do top da pagina.

*É meio complicado de explicar, mas espero que tenha entendido :)*